# Firebug's HTML in the HTML tab is grayed not, therefore not visible on the page itself.. why?

Tags: jquery, html, firebug

So here's the deal- I'm using AJAX to load page content via XML files. The content gets loaded correctly, no problem there. But, when I load a specific piece of HTML, Firebug shows it as grayed out, and I know from looking online that means it's not visible on the page itself, which is true in my case- I do not see that div on the page.  The question is, why is this piece grayed out???? PLEASE HELP!! I'm totally stuck!!

The screen shot of the HTML from Firebug is below. Towards the bottom notice there are two divs that are grayed out. Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: what does `display:none;` mean?

Answer (score 9):

It could be that through a class or property you have this set:

```
display: none;
```

so check the styles for those DIVs...

**Edit:**
Your screenshot even shows that one directly has this property...

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Stupid me, that was it.